# SSH Tunnel Inside SSL

Tags: windows, linux, ssl, ssh, tunnel

Someone can explain me which tools and how i have to use to setup SSH tunnel encapsulated in SSL on both server and client sides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better still, why would you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stunnel seems to do what you are waiting for : http://www.stunnel.org/?page=docs

It creates some SSL tunnel, and you can put any protocol you want : HTTP, POP, IMAP, SSH etc..

Hope it helps